# Microsoft Graph Authentication Token Issue

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am new to Microsoft Graph and SharePoint Framework. Recently developing spfx webpart with Graph API's integration.

I have registered the app in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com portal and AAD implementation through `hello.js`.

The first time browsing to the page, it redirects to Microsoft app login page and prompt for credentials.

Once authentication successful then it's working fine, from then on it does not prompt for credentials.

Is there any possiblities to access MS Graph API directly using Application Id, and Secret without prompting for login?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will want to use the client credential flow to do this. You will only have access to organizational data (/me won't work for example, but /users will). There is an article on getting access [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service).

You will need to log in as an admin one time per application to authorize your app to use your tenant's data. You can do this at:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/adminconsent?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&state=12345
&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions
```